Finding where these instances used which consuming more memory
I'm debugging/analyzing Springboot application using VisualVm and Eclipse Memory analyzer tools to find out where heap memory used more. After that plan is to see how can we avoid such instances to reduce the over all application memory usage.
Heap dump overview in VisualVm is showing that below are the instance using more memory,

Question here is, is there a way to find out what are the unnecessary instances out of this number? We are okay to do the code restructure.

The question is too broad for [so]. There are no simple answers. You need a deep understanding of the application objects and their Java objects to identify their relationship. You need experience in analyzing heap dumps.

I understood that, so expecting some guidance or some useful sources to learn it.

Recommendations of off-site resources is offtopic in [so].
